# Comment réintituler sans inclure la réponse ?

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

Le cas surgit¹ avec cette question : [« Son imbécile de mari » : comment s'appelle cette tournure de phrase ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/comment-sappelle-cette-tournure-de-phrase). Le titre est très générique, il me semble indispensable de le changer (avant d'avoir 19 autres questions intitulées pareil, par exemple), seulement… comment ?

Même si en l'occurence, « *Comment s'appelle cette tournure sans nom ?* » n'est même pas une option, on peut imaginer que « *Comment appelle-t-on la passivation ?* » ou « *Comment appelle-t-on l'inversion du sujet ?* » en seront à peine plus, le cas échéant.

En particulier, la personne qui cherchera la question ne connaîtra vraisemblablement *pas* la réponse, donc quels pourraient être les meilleurs mots-clefs pour et les trouver, et les différencier les unes des autres ?

¹  <sub>Par contre, je n'ai pas compris pourquoi mon drapal était rejeté si mon idée était encouragée…</sub>

---

How to improve very broad titles without including the answer in them ? In [this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1662/comment-sappelle-cette-tournure-de-phrase), the same title could apply to many more similar questions, therefore it seems compulsory to change it. Only how to do so ?

"What's the name of `structure's name`?" isn't much of an option, and the one who'll be searching for it won't know the answer either anyway. **What keywords would make these questions findable, as well as distinguishable ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans un cas comme celui-ci, je pense que le mieux est d'inclure un exemple dans le titre.

> « Son imbécile de mari » : comment s'appelle cette tournure ?

L'autre question sur la même tournure a choisi une manière différente : un exemple générique — « Grammaticalité de « il y a <nom> d'<adjectif> » ». Autant garder des formulations différentes sur les questions voisines ou doublonnes, ça augmente les chances que quelqu'un a de tomber sur une d'entre elles.

<sub>Pour ce qui est du signal, ni éditer une question ni poser une question sur méta ne demandent l'intervention d'un modérateur, donc le modérateur a dû se demander ce que tu voulais qu'il fasse.</sub>

Comment: Soit, je peux accepter ça si personne n'a mieux. Ça peut même traiter le cas général. Par contre, je n'ai pas réussi à écrire `<chose>` sans code, sans me le faire manger (à la prévisualisation du moins), et je ne peux pas t'éditer pour voir la source : comment fais-tu ? (¹ et ok, merci)